# SQL summary count group function

Tags: sql

hey guys i have been looking and trying, but cant get it work maybe s1 can help me real quick.

i have this sample

```
NAME |  QTY | LOC
-----|------|----
Noo4 |  312 | A13
Noo4 |  188 | A13 
Noo6 |  123 | A13
Noo4 |  786 | A88
Noo6 |  455 | A77
```

this is my expected result

```
NAME |  QTY | LOC
-----|------|----
Noo4 |  500 | A13
Noo6 |  123 | A13
Noo4 |  786 | A88
Noo6 |  455 | A77
```

Comment: Do you want to group by name and loc?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seem you need  sum() group  by

```
select name, sum(qty), loc 
from my_table  
group by name, loc
```

Comment: Do you understand the question?

Comment: i think  the OP  show the first as data sample and the second as expetced  result  ..